# Is it true that $P = coNP$?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

I have recently read the definition of $coNP := \{L \ \mid \ \overline{L} \in P\}$, where $L$ denotes a language. However, I am wondering what the difference between $P$ and $coNP$ is, since an elementary result of the theory of Turing Machines is that if $L \in P$, then $\overline{L} \in P$.

So is $P = coNP$ or is there something that I am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P=coNP$ is an open question, equivalent to the famous: "is $P=NP$ true?" question.

The definition of $coNP$ you have is incorrect. The correct definition is the following:

$$coNP:=\{L\mid \overline{L}\in NP\}$$
As you can see, it reads $NP$ and **not** $P$. It was probably a typo wherever you saw that definition.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. I was using the online (draft) version of Arora and Barak from https://theory.cs.princeton.edu/complexity/  The error there is on page 218. That clears it up, thanks for your help.